# Volley string request - some won't be sended

Tags: android-volley, http-get

I'm developing an app heavly based on HTTP GET request to retreive user' data and choice, so i've decided to use Volley.

I've created a common RequestQueue for all the whole application and when I need a request I add a stringRequest to that queue.

The problem of mine is that some requests will be sended but other will not, I think that I've reached a max number of request or something similar, beacuse the stringRequest's URL is correct and writing it in my browser URL's bar I get data I want.

How can I solve this situation?